# Are there specific VGA cables that support 60Hz vs. 75Hz for 1080p?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, resolution, vga

Has anyone successfully used a VGA cable with a monitor to display 1920x1080 resolution @ 75Hz?

I have an old laptop with a VGA port which supports 1920x1080 @ 75Hz (vendor's manual states so). I have a monitor that supports the same settings. However I'm only getting 60Hz at that resolution. Are there specific VGA cables that support 60Hz vs. 75Hz for 1080p?

Comment: Changed the question to remove the shopping request and clarify the title.

Comment: You need a monitor that supports it, and I think the higher refresh rates were meant for CRTs